# Why can't an email or profile scope used to authenticate in OAuth?

Tags: oauth, oauth2

I am trying to learn OAuth and I keep reading that "OAuth is only used for authorization." However, if you add an email or profile scope, doesn't that identify who the user is? So can it be used for both authorization and authentication?

I understand this overlaps with OIDC's scope, but I'm simply adding a scope to OAuth.

Comment: OIDC does so much more than just “add a scope”… to do what you suggest you should replicate all the identifying steps…. Which are more than simply adding a scope.

Comment: That's what I meant, hence "overlaps". My point was to not think about OIDC for a second and just focus on OAuth. Imagine a time when OIDC didn't exist. If you add a scope called email, doesn't that identify who the user is? So are these articles saying that OAuth is only used for authorization actually false?

Comment: OIDC is made to use oAuth 2 and to solve the exact problem…. Ignoring it means you can never learn from it. You are basically asking to ignore the wheel and ponder what we could use to make moving this pile bricks easier while using this wooden box…

Comment: What does adding the scopes should do? Just adding some scopes does not identify the user.